# How to detect if Autofill is enabled for this app

Tags: android, android-service, android-autofill-manager

I set the autofill service to be using my android app service at Settings > Additional Settings > Language & input > Autofill service.

Now in my app is there a way to check if the autofill service is set to this app?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here we need to get a bridge to our react native app to execute native code https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services?hl=hr#prompt